# Oh-my-zsh + iTerm + PhpStorm

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm

I'm using [oh-my-zsh](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh) with iTerm. I'm using the default `robbyrussell` theme for `zsh`, but I've changed the theme color, the font, disabled bold text and increased line height in iTerm settings. If I open iTerm everything is like I want to.

[image]

When using PhpStorm Terminal it uses the `zsh` but the line height is the original one and the bold text is there. PhpStorm seems to get the default `zsh` configuration, not the iTerm customizations I've made:

[image]

Anyone knows how I can apply the same look and feel I have in iTerm in PhpStorm Terminal? I already increased the line height and remove bold text in PhpStorm settings, but they remain the same.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-127316

Comment: I am also facing this issues does anyone has the solution to this